# PHP eval and heredoc don't play nicely

Tags: php, eval, heredoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [heredoc with eval code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264981/heredoc-with-eval-code-execution)

So I have the following in function.php:

```
eval("\$content = <<<TEMPLATE\n
               asdf
\nTEMPLATE;");
```

And I keep getting an error saying:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or T_END_HEREDOC or T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES or T_CURLY_OPEN in /var/www/function.php(10) : eval()'d code on line 5
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is. There is obviously an ending for the heredoc syntax, does heredoc just not like to play nice with eval?

Comment: Why would you do such a thing?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This looks like all kinds of bad. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Even with TEMPLATE; on its own line it doesn't work.

Comment: @NullUserException I thought that too, but wouldn't the \n be interpreted as a newline *before* the string is evalled at all?

Comment: @GolezTrol Hmmm, it makes sense. I didn't catch the quotes.

Comment: I agree with @NullUserException. Please explain what you are trying to do so we can properly help you / prevent you from doing "stupid" things. `eval()` is considered `evil`.

Comment: I wouldn't do this either, but it makes you wonder why it isn't possible. I think it would be more challenging to answer the question than to save this user from doing stupid things. We have made our points. :0

Comment: Very interesting theoretical question. But I see no actual uses in practice. What are you trying to do? I'm 99% sure there's a better solution.

Comment: HTML templates where you can use php variables, I know MyBB uses it as do many other packages that use templating.

Comment: @legion Don't do that. Just because someone else is doing it doesn't mean they're doing it right. In general, I would avoid using templating engines in PHP, period - because PHP itself *is* a templating engine. There *is* a better solution, it's called [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Look at how an MVC framework handles views (templates): http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html. You get (somewhat) clean HTML, without losing performance or flexibility.

Comment: I'm not too worried about it I'm just doing it for a class so that my partner who doesn't know PHP can just create the HTML/CSS files elsewhere and I don't have to worry about integrating the PHP in those files. I would normally just use php directly in the template itself but its easier for him this way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HEREDOC syntax is ended by the delimiter defined at the start, followed by a semicolon, ***followed by a newline***. You do not have the newline, therefore it is not being recognised as the end of the HEREDOC. Add an extra `\n` after `TEMPLATE;` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you that was it and I feel stupid now, I kept thinking it was before hand.